# if statement for adding users into groups in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm currently working on some code to add local users into groups and I'm pretty stuck. The issue occurs when executing these six lines :

```
if /I "%choix%"=="1" do net localgroup %grp1% %%A /add
if /I "%choix%"=="2" do net localgroup %grp2% %%A /add
if /I "%choix%"=="3" do (
    net localgroup %grp1% %%A /add
    net localgroup %grp2% %%A /add
)
```

Here is my complete code :

```
@ echo off

:debut
set /P fichiercsv="Complete file path :"
set /P grp1="Enter the first group name :"
set /P grp2="Enter the second group name :"
net localgroup %grp1% /add
net localgroup %grp2% /add
for /F "eol=; tokens=1,2 delims=," %%A in (%fichiercsv%) do net user %%A %%B /add
pause
for /F "eol=; tokens=1,2 delims=," %%A in (%fichiercsv%) do (
    cls
    echo In which group do you want to add %%A?
    echo 1. %grp1%
    echo 2. %grp2%
    echo 3. %grp1% et %grp2%
    set /P choix="Enter a number : "
    if /I "%choix%"=="1" do net localgroup %grp1% %%A /add
    if /I "%choix%"=="2" do net localgroup %grp2% %%A /add
    if /I "%choix%"=="3" do (
        net localgroup %grp1% %%A /add
        net localgroup %grp2% %%A /add
    )
)

echo All users where added to the groups
echo Do you want to specify another file ?
set /P continuer="continue whit another csv file [o/n] ?"
if /I "%continuer%" EQU "o" goto debut
if /I "%continuer%" EQU "n" goto fin

:fin
echo Resultat final:
type %fichiercsv%
echo Au revoir !
```

Comment: please take a look at [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: What *issue* occurs? You've not explained a problem or asked a question; *I'm pretty stuck* is not a meaningful or useful problem statement. What **exactly** is the problem with the code you've posted, and what **specific question** are you asking?